# Knockout.js: <li> not being displayed in template

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to Knockout.js. And following is my problem:

The list items displayed for Primary and Extended filters should only display relevant items. they should not display empty items, image attached.

[ListItems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI4qF.jpg)

```
    <script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="primaryFilterItem">    
    <li class="filterItem not-draggable" data-bind="if:isPrimary, css:{selected:hasFocus, draggable:!isStatic}, click:$root.selectFilter">
        <span data-bind="text:name" />
        <div class="removeButton button" data-bind="click:$root.removeFilter" title='@Html.T("Common.Remove.Tooltip","remove")'></div>
        <span class="priority" data-bind="text:linkboxPriority, css:{hidden:linkboxPriority()==0}"></span>
    </li>    
</script>

<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="extendedFilterItem">    
    <li class="filterItem not-draggable" data-bind="ifnot:isPrimary, css:{selected:hasFocus, draggable:!isStatic}, click:$root.selectFilter">
        <span data-bind="text:name" />
        <div class="addButton" data-bind="click:$root.addToPrimaryFilter" title='@Html.T("Common.Add.Tooltip","add")'></div>
        <span class="priority" data-bind="text:linkboxPriority, css:{hidden:linkboxPriority()==0}"></span>
    </li>    
</script>


<div class="guiFilter">
    <div class="left">
        <h3 data-bind="if:(3==3 && selectedGuiFilters()!=null && selectedGuiFilters().length>0)">
            @Html.T("Admin.Filter.Sortable.Used.Text", "used filter")
        </h3>
        @*<h3 data-bind="if:selectedGuiFilters().length==0">no filters used</h3>*@
        <h4 data-bind="if:(3==3 && selectedGuiFilters()!=null && selectedGuiFilters().length>0)">
            @Html.T("Admin.Filter.Primary.Text", "Primary filter")
        </h4>
        <ol class="listView" data-bind="sortable:{template:'primaryFilterItem', data:selectedGuiFilters,options: { axis: 'y'}, afterMove:invalidate}"></ol>

        <h4 data-bind="if:(3==3 && selectedGuiFilters()!=null && selectedGuiFilters().length>0)">
            @Html.T("Admin.Filter.Extended.Text", "Extended filter")
        </h4>
        <ol class="listView" data-bind="sortable:{template:'extendedFilterItem', data:selectedGuiFilters,options: { axis: 'y'}, afterMove:invalidate}"></ol>

        @*<ol class="listView" data-bind="sortable:{template:'filterItem', data:selectedGuiFilters,options: { axis: 'y'}, afterMove:invalidate}"></ol>*@
        <ol class="listView" data-bind="template:{name:'filterItem', foreach:specialFilters}"></ol>

        <h3 data-bind="if:(unselectedGuiFilters()!=null && unselectedGuiFilters().length>0)">
            @Html.T("Admin.Filter.Sortable.Available.Text", "available filter")
        </h3>
        <ol class="listView" data-bind="template:{name:'unselectedfilterItem', foreach:unselectedGuiFilters}"></ol>
    </div>

    <div class="right" data-bind="template:{name: selectedType()+'Template', data:selectedFilter}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear from your question and code example what your exact problem is. I'm assuming here that you are using if: IsPrimary as the logic for whether to display the li or not and you are getting empty li's rendered to your view, and this is the problem.

The if binding applied to the li, will affect the descendents of the element. In this case your span etc. This is why you are getting empty li elements rendered in your view.

From the Knockout documentation http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

> The if binding, however, physically adds or removes the contained markup in your DOM, and only applies bindings to descendants if the expression is true.

In this case, try moving your if binding to a containerless binding outside your li tags.

```html
<h3>This will display empty list items</h3>
<ul data-bind="foreach: ListItems">
  <li data-bind="if: ShowListItem">
    <span data-bind="text: $index"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
<h3>This won't display empty list items</h3>
<ul data-bind="foreach: ListItems">
  <!-- ko if: ShowListItem -->
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: $index"></span>
  </li>
  <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

See working example here http://plnkr.co/edit/eZe2mhXiemGbB4eDYJSy?p=preview